# Camunda and job manager

Tags: camunda

I'm going to use BPMN Camunda as an asynchronous job executor.

I need to run workflow for multiple items parallelly.

Let say I have group1 which contains item1..item5 and
group2 which contains item11..item20.

I need to track progress per group, so for separate progress for group1 and separate for group2.

So, in this case, I'm starting 15 workflows (5 in group1 and 10 in group2), one for each item (item is an argument of such flow).

I noticed that I need some/extra job manager for this to track the progress in groups that I need to write on my own or ...

... Or maybe there is some mechanism in Camunda which will do this for me.

... Or maybe I can start some parent jobs each for the group and those parent jobs will start item jobs, and can get progress from parent jobs.

What options do I have here to archive that?

Comment: Hard to give good advice without having more information - but did you already have a look at multiple instance? That could probably solve your problem (or parts of it) within one workflow definition: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.8/reference/bpmn20/tasks/task-markers/#multiple-instance

Comment: Looks very good to me. I'm not so familiar with Camunda it is my beginning. I had doubts writing this post if I was clear enough, but you were able to help me even though. I didn't know about those multiple instances. Great thanks.